# Как обновить autowired коллекцию Spring

Tags: java, spring

Имеется коллекция объектов

```
@Autowired
private List<SomeInterface> objects;
```

В рантайме создаю новую реализацию интерфейса SomeInterface, 
Как сделать , чтобы спринг обновил эту коллекцию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете сделать так:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

public Collection<SomeInterface> getList(){
   return context.getBeansOfType(SomeInterface.class);
}
```

Но, чтобы это правильно работало, необходимо вашу новую реализацию зарегистрировать в контексте `spring'a` .

Например так:

```
((DefaultListableBeanFactory)context
                  .getAutowiredCapableBeanFactory())
                  .registerSingleton(new SomeInterfaceImpl());
```

Comment: Мне кажется не стоит инжектить контекст в бины :)

Comment: Да, согласен, злоупотреблять этим не стоит, но иногда все таки без этого не обойтись)

Comment: В данном случае, наверное, можно через lookup-метод сделать.